# Negation of a statement about a proof in topology.

Tags: general-topology, logic

I am doing a exercise in topology where I need to prove that a certain $\tau_1\neq\tau_2$ and for that I need the negation of the following statement.

> $$\text{for each} \;B\in \mathcal{B}_2\text{ and each }x\in B,\exists \;B^{'}\in\mathcal{B}_1 \text{ such that } x\in B^{'} \subseteq B$$

I have no exposition to symbolic logic so I was trying to negate this statement using kind of "brute force" I want to know is it correct?

> There exists a $B\in \mathcal{B}_2$ for which where exists a $x\in B$ such that $\forall$ ($B^{'}\in \mathcal{B}_1$), $B^{'}$ never satisfies $x\in B^{'}\subseteq B$ which means that either $x\notin B^{'}$ or $B^{'}\not\subset B$.

Which means i will have  to prove that that not even a single $B^{'}$ will satisfy the property that $x\in B^{'}\subseteq B$. So my objective should be only to focus on the fact that both of them are not satisfied simultaneously ever in my counterexample, since if one of those property is not satisfied such a $B^{'}$ is already trivially ruled out to check further.

Comment: You're quite right: you need to find one $B \in \mathcal{B_2}$ and one $x \in B$ such that for all $B' \in \mathcal{B}_1$ we cannot have $x \in B' \subseteq B$. So we only need to consider $B'$ that contain $x$ and show that $B ' \not \subseteq B$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma , just one question, what about those $B^{'}$ which are a subset of $B$, will I have to show that those set doesn't contain $x$ ?

Comment: $[\neg[\forall x \;(p(x)]\iff \exists x\;(\neg p(x)).$  And $[\neg \forall x\in y\;(p(x)]\iff \exists x\in y\;(\neg p(x)).$  And move the "$\neg$" to the beginning of the RHS in each of these for negations of "$\;\exists$". Apply this in stages in your Q, moving the "$\neg$" further to the right in the expression at each stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal logic approach:
The statement you want to negate is

> $$\forall B ( B \in \mathcal{B_2} \rightarrow \forall x: \left(x \in B \rightarrow \exists B': (B' \in \mathcal{B_1} \land x \in B' \land (\forall y \in B': y \in B)\right)$$ removing all text and definitions (like inclusion symbols).

Try to formally negate this, using a.o. $\lnot (p \to q )\leftrightarrow (p \land \lnot q)$

I prefer the reasoning way: The statement in words is: whatever $B \in \mathcal{B_2}$ you start with, for any $x$ in $B$ there is some member of $\mathcal{B_1}$ that contains $x$ and sits inside $B$. (this says in topological terms: any member of $\mathcal{B_2}$ is open in a topology that contains all of $\mathcal{B_1}$).

So to contradict this there must be *some* $B \in \mathcal{B_2}$ and some fixed $x \in B$ such that $x$ is **not** an interior point w.r.t. a topology generated by $\mathcal{B_1}$, so for *all* $B' \in \mathcal{B_1}$ that contain $x$ , $B'$ "must stick out of" $B$ ($B' \not \subseteq B$), so for all $B' \in \mathcal{B_1}$ with $x \in B'$ there is some $y \in B' \setminus B$.

Answer (score 1):

You got the right idea, and the second statement is the correct negation of the first statement. Whenever negating a sentence with universal quantifiers ($\forall$, for all) and existential quantifiers ($\exists$, there exists), there is a simple scheme for doing so. Progress through the sentence from left to right, changing each universal quantifier to an existential quantifier, and each existential quantifier to a universal quantifier, and negating any other statement not already attached to a quantifier. That is, you would change "for all $B \in C$, $B \subseteq C$" to "there exists $B \in C$ such that $B \not\subseteq C$" upon negation. Note that $B \subseteq C$ changed to $B \not\subseteq C$, but $B \in C$ remained $B \in C$ because $B \in C$ is attached to a quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of
for all B in B2, for all x in B,
. . there's some B' in B1 with x in B' subset B
is
some B in B2, some x in B with for all B' in B1,
. . either x not in B1 or not B' subset of B.

The negation of
. . B' subset B,
is the negation of
. . for all y in B', y in B

which is
some y in B' with y not in B.